# Visual Studio WPF Media Element Video Not Playing in Exe Build

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, video, executable, mediaelement

I am creating a Visual Studio 2019 WPF Program that includes a video tutorial for users.
The video plays in the visual studio environment, however, when I build the application and install the exe the video no longer plays, a blank screen appears and it seems to never load.

So far I've tried setting the video properties:
Build Action = "Content" and
Copy to output Directory = "Copy Always/Copy if Newer".

```
XAML Code
<Grid Grid.Column="1">
   <MediaElement Name="media" LoadedBehavior="Manual"  
   UnloadedBehavior="Manual" 
   Source="./Resources/Tool_Tutorial.mp4"></MediaElement>
</Grid>

Code to start video
        public TutorialVideos() 
        {
            try
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                media.Play();
            }catch (Exception ex){
                System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
```

File Structure
Program-> Resources -> Tool_Tutorial.mp4
Tutorial.xaml

The video size is 51mbs.

Is there anything else I could try?

Comment: Please share the line of code that loads the video, and also the folder structure of your Solution Explorer where the video resides.  Both play a role in how the video is found to be played.  You could also wrap your code in a try/catch to find the exact exception that is occurring.

Comment: Thank you, I have included my code and file structure. I have also tried adding a try catch statement however no error occurred. The video plays when I run the program in Visual Studio but not when I build and run the exe.

Comment: Hi,@ConorCodes. It may be that resources cannot be accessed through the file path during application deployment, you could try to refer to [Pack URIs in WPF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/app-development/pack-uris-in-wpf?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) to set the deployment file path.

Comment: Hello @HuiLiu-MFST , Thank you for your response. I have tried changing the source of the MediaElement to:
<MediaElement Name="media" LoadedBehavior="Manual"  UnloadedBehavior="Manual" Source="pack://siteoforigin:,,,/Resources/Tool_Tutorial.mp4"></MediaElement>

However, the video still plays in the Visual Studio IDE and not in the exe.

Comment: @ConorCodes I followed your instructions exactly and could not reproduce the issue. [Full sample app here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1a3zerVKZkakZakpBlRBMJ_2WOeqZmhGA/view?usp=sharing) I was able to compile this and run it from both Visual Studio and also the .exe from File Explorer.  See if you can run the attached source code.  If not, then the problem is outside of your code, perhaps a graphics issue (try rebooting to see if it goes away). Or, you could have a packaging issue with your installer.

Answer (score 0):

Try including this method into your event handler to check if the source file exists before playing it:

```
private void PlaySourceFile(string source)
{
    //check 2 times - second one to play, first to choose if not found
    if(!File.Exists(source)){
    {
        OpenFileDialog dialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        if (dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) // == true for .Net Core/.Net Standard
        {
            source = dialog?.FileName;
        }
    }
    if(File.Exists(source))
    {
        media?.Source = new Uri(source);
        media?.Play();
    }
}
```